# How to connect with line shapes/labels on runtime?

Tags: c#, runtime, graphics2d

I want to create on runtime labels/shapes and after that to connect shapes with line like how you do it in Visio.

With this code I am creating the "block":

```
    private void createBlock() {
                try {
                    Label label = new Label();
                    label.AutoSize = false;
                    label.Location = Control.MousePosition;
                    label.Size = new Size(89, 36);
                    label.BackColor = Color.DarkOliveGreen;
                    label.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    label.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                    label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    label.Text = "New Block";
                    label.ContextMenuStrip = contextBlock;
                    canvas.Controls.Add(label);
                    MoveBlock(label);                
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

With this I am moving the objects in the form:

```
private void MoveBlock(Label block, Label endBlock=null){
                 block.MouseDown += (ss, ee) => {
                    if (ee.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) fPoint = Control.MousePosition;                     
                };
                 block.MouseMove += (ss, ee) => {
                     if (ee.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) {
                         Point temp = Control.MousePosition;
                         Point res = new Point(fPoint.X - temp.X, fPoint.Y - temp.Y);

                         block.Location = new Point(block.Location.X - res.X, block.Location.Y - res.Y);
                         fPoint = temp;

                     }
                 }; 
            }
```

How do I actually do that? At least how to search for it? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You will need to define connectors in the shapes and think of rules how they should be used. Next you need a lines class that holds two blocks and info about the line (width, style etc). Finally your paint code can draw them. - Note that you may want to change the connectors used whenever you move a block to make the lines go in a most direct way.  Of course the big question will be: What lines do you plan to do: straight and simple or multisegment lines to go around the blocks. This is a lot of work..

Comment: I simply want straight lines from one block to other and when I move the block, the line must go with it.

Comment: The most direct approach, though not the best looking, is to draw the line between the midpoints of the blocks. You need to maintain a list of tuples of blocks.. If you draw them into a Bitmap and set it to be the BackgroundImage of the canvas. You need to re-create that bitmap upon each movment of the labels.

Comment: I want to use the Graphics class. There is any name for this to search, is called somehow? Do you have some guides where to start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a minimal example how you can start by changing and expanding your code a little:

[image]

first we create a class level variable to hold the list of connected blocks:

```
List<Tuple<Label, Label>> lines = new List<Tuple<Label, Label>>();
```

You may want to use a class of your own instead of the cheap `Tuples` to hold more info about the lines, like color, pen style, width etc..

Next we make the `createBlock` method return the new `Label`, so we can use it directly..

```
private Label createBlock()          <---- for convenience!
{
    try
    {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.AutoSize = false;
        label.Location = Control.MousePosition;
        label.Size = new Size(89, 36);
        label.BackColor = Color.DarkOliveGreen;
        label.ForeColor = Color.White;
        label.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        label.Text = "New Block";
        label.ContextMenuStrip = contextBlock;
        canvas.Controls.Add(label);
        MoveBlock(label);
        return label;                <---- for convenience!
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is how I use it in my `Form Load` event:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label l1 = createBlock();
    Label l2 = createBlock();

    lines.Add(new Tuple<Label, Label>(l1,l2));
}
```

It is probably a good idea to put each block into a `List<Label>` or (`List<Block>` once you have upgraded them to a class `Block`) to access them later, so you don't have to wade through the `canvas.Controls` collection..

To make it show the lines, we need to trigger the `Paint` event each time a line is added or moved:

```
private void MoveBlock(Label block, Label endBlock = null)
{
    block.MouseDown += (ss, ee) =>
    {
        if (ee.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) 
            fPoint = Control.MousePosition;
    };
    block.MouseMove += (ss, ee) =>
    {
        if (ee.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Point temp = Control.MousePosition;
            Point res = new Point(fPoint.X - temp.X, fPoint.Y - temp.Y);

            block.Location = new Point(block.Location.X - res.X,
                                       block.Location.Y - res.Y);
            fPoint = temp;
            canvas.Invalidate();   // <------- draw the new lines
        }
    };
}
```

I hope your canvas is double buffered (or that canvas is a `PictureBox`)!

Here is a simple implementation of drawing the lines:

```
private void canvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Tuple<Label, Label> t in lines)
    {
        Point p1 = new Point(t.Item1.Left + t.Item1.Width / 2, 
                             t.Item1.Top + t.Item1.Height / 2);
        Point p2 = new Point(t.Item2.Left + t.Item2.Width / 2, 
                             t.Item2.Top + t.Item2.Height / 2);

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, p1, p2);
    }
}
```

There are many things to improve but it works and is rather simple. The lines are behind the Labels and as long you don't overcrowd the canvas they look rather natural..

There are many things to learn about Winforms Graphics but they are well beyond the scope of this post..

Comment: I need my blocks to be created dynamically, May the user have 50 or 3 and the connections to be customed/dynamically.

Comment: Of course you can do that.  I just hard-coded a simple example. But the two blocks are in fact created dynamically. - Just make sure to think of a nice and intuitive interface for the user. You will have to think ahead of many things, expecially if a block can be connected to multiple other blocks.. Let the UI drive the development. One common way is to have a 'Connect' tool: You chose is the user is prompted to click on one and then a second block; the you connect them by creating the new line...

Comment: ..You should also have a way to 'select' a block and then show editable info about it, including all lines and offer to modify them. But of course all this is up to you!

Comment: That's exactly what I want.